# Let $p=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$,$ q=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ix^i+(-a_n)x^n$. If I know the roots of $p$, do I know anything about the roots of $q$?

Tags: polynomials

Let $p=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$,$ q=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ix^i+(-a_n)x^n$.

If I know the roots of $p$, do I know anything about the roots of $q$?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to mind is that the roots of both $p$ and $q$ must lie in an open disk of radius $R$, where $R$ is such that $|a_n||x|^n > \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |a_i||x|^i$ for all $|x|>R$.

This is true since if $x\geq R$ then  $\left|\sum a_i x^i \right| \geq |a_n| |x|^n - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |a_i||x|^i>0$. Such an $R$ will exist because, dividing by $|x|^n$, we see that we just need to take $R$ such that
$$|a_n| \geq \frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|x|} + \dotsb + \frac{|a_1|}{|x|^{n-1}} + \frac{|a_0|}{|x|^n}\quad \text{for all $x >R$}.$$

Comment: That's nice, how'd you arrive to that? An open or a closed disk?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Edited.

Comment: You also know something about the number of roots for $q$, (assuming you know a priori the number of roots of $p$) via Rouche's theorem. Again, this is only true on an open disk such that $p>q$.

Comment: @KevinSheng $p$ and $q$ have the same degree, so they have the same number of roots.

Comment: @KevinSheng The only difference between $p$ and $q$ is that the sign of the leading coefficient is reversed.

Comment: You're right, I was confusing the definition with subtraction from $ p $